# ROPC policy - B2C to B2C Migration - Copy Authentication methods

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

This is specifically for a scenario where there are two azure ad b2c tenants e.g. legacy and latest and user migration needs to be done in a seamless way.

The ropc policy example here https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/B2C2B2CMigration works best to achieve this, however looking for a suggestion to extend it further so that user's authentication methods from legacy tenant can also be copied while user gets written to the new tenant.

The [extension file](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/B2C2B2CMigration/Policy/B2CMigrate_Extensions.xml) given in the sample showcases a way how user attributes can be mapped and imported while user gets written to the new tenant and here is a sample of it

```
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isLocalUser" DefaultValue="false" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
</OutputClaims>
```

But this does not provide any guidance around copying authentication methods of the user so looking forward for a suggestion if  - there is any way if user in legacy tenant has setup the verification phone number in Authentication method (either while setting up MFA or SSPR) then copy that information along with attributes as shown above and set it as authentication information for user in the new tenant too? If yes, what is the best way to achieve it?

Refer image below that highlights the information to be copied while copying the user with ROPC policy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The attributes used for this are:

```
<ClaimType Id="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber">
    <DisplayName>Phone Number</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <Mask Type="Simple">XXX-XXX-</Mask>
    <UserHelpText>Your telephone number</UserHelpText>
</ClaimType>

<ClaimType Id="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber">
    <DisplayName>Verified Phone Number</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="phone_number"/>
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <Mask Type="Simple">XXX-XXX-</Mask>
    <UserHelpText>Your office phone number that has been verified</UserHelpText>
</ClaimType>
```

Comment: Yes have observed it, however when used in the <OutputClaims> section of the extention.xml shown above - it does not work and does not copy authentication methods i.e. phone number of the user from old to new tenant.

Comment: We ended up raising a support ticket for this and got official response that the authentication method information from the user profile won't be copied at this point and it is by design since the ROPC does not support this scenario.